# Category loop is showing all post titles (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, categories

I can't seem to get this to work properly.

This code is supposed to loop through all categories in a custom taxonomy and show the post titles under each category heading:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'taxonomy'  => 'news_category',
    'orderby'   => 'name'
);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    echo '<h2>' . $category->name . '</h2>'; ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
            <li>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </li>
        <?php 
    } ?>      
    </ul>
<?php
}
```

The expected result is this...

**Category 1**

- A post title
- Another post title

**Category 2**

- Yet another post title

**Category 3**

- Hey look, another post title
- And one more post title just for fun

...but what I am getting is this:

**Category 1**

- A post title
- Another post title
- Yet another post title
- Hey look, another post title
- And one more post title just for fun

**Category 2**

- A post title
- Another post title
- Yet another post title
- Hey look, another post title
- And one more post title just for fun

**Category 3**

- A post title
- Another post title
- Yet another post title
- Hey look, another post title
- And one more post title just for fun

How to I fix this?

Comment: What result are you getting instead?

Comment: Each call to `$posts = get_posts($args);` will return every post. You have to get the posts *from* the current category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because when you are going with get_posts you are not specifying any taxonomy term to search into, since you are using again your $args var and it just contains general parameters to fetch your categories.

To make it the way you want it you should replace the $args when calling get_posts with something like this:

```
$postArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'news_category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $category->slug,
        ),
    ),
);
$posts = get_posts($postArgs);
```

The exact documentation of what you can do is available here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters.

WP_Query work the same as get_posts